# Data Snapshot output option is not visible under the Scheduler in JasperReports Server v6.2.0

Tags: jasperserver

I have enabled the Data Snapshots on Jasper Reports Server v6.2.0 as per the JasperReports Server Administrative Guide. After the restart, Data Snapshot option is not visible under the Output section of Reports Scheduler.

Here is the screenshot provided in the documentation but for me Data Snapshot option does not appear

[image]

Do I need some more changes beyond what is mentioned in the doc. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks